# How to show error message until input is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with server-side validation. and if server returns validation errors I want to show them in the form, but only until user edited anything.

Ideally I want to have something like:

```
<form name='MyForm' ng-submit='doSomething()'>
    <label for='my-field-id'>Some field</label>
    <input type='text' id='my_field_id' ng-model='myField' name='my_field'>
    <div ng-show-if-changed='MyForm.my_field.serverSideError'
         ng-show-until='MyForm.my_field.changed'>Error!</div>
</form>
```

How to achieve this behavior? I really want to avoid to put this logic in a controller, and want to come up with some smart reusable directive.

### UPDATE

Main thing here is how to implement `ng-show-until-changed` functionality. The logic of it must be "if an element is shown and target is changed - hide it". And the questions here:

- if target will be just some scope variable, like `MyForm.my_field.serverSideError` - will I need to manually launch `$digest` when it may be changed? For example after AJAX request will be completed, and so probably some errors can arrive from the server? How to properly watch for these server-side errors changes ?
- What is a proper way to hide/show some element in a custom directive in a same way as `ng-show` directive does that? is there some built-in utilites for that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and crudest way is to add a text-box to the form, and make it read-only so the user can't do anything with it.  But you can still use JavaScript to put text into the box, such as the error message you get from the server.  And of course you can erase the text any time (triggered by, say, an `onkeydown` event-handler for the data-entry-field that the user edits).

A similar and more elegant way involves a `<p>` element in the HTML of your form, located near the place where you expect the user to do some editing:

```
<p id="errmsg">&nbsp;</p>
```

In your Javascript you would do something like this, to prepare:

```
var P=document.getElementById("errmsg");
```

and then, when you need to display an error message from the server:

```
P.innerHTML="Text of error message";
```

and when the user begins editing (again, detect with an `onkeydown` event handler), you can replace the error-message text with another `&nbsp;`

If you really want to do hide/show of error messages, you might consider constructing several paragraphs, all with the same number of lines.  Each would contain a pre-written error message, although one of them might be instructions regarding data that is supposed to be entered.  That's the one to show by-default.  All the paragraphs can be stacked up in the same place on the form, this way:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
 <p id="p1" style="position:absolute;top='0px';left='0px';" hidden="">paragraph 1 text</p>
 <p id="p2" style="position:absolute;top='0px';left='0px';" hidden="hidden">paragraph 2</p>
 <p id="p3" style="position:absolute;top='0px';left='0px';" hidden="hidden">paragraph 3</p>
</div>
<br /> <!-- you will discover that some line-breaks are needed here -->
<br />
```

You would again use JavaScript to getElementById() of each paragraph, perhaps into an array of P[] variables.  Then you can hide or display any of the paragraphs with

```
P[x].hidden="hidden";
P[x].hidden="";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the error message when the model changes and show it again when errors occure on submit.
See sample below or in this [plunker][1]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="changeExample">
  <!-- snippet adapted from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange. -->
  <script>
    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
          var model;

          function simulateError(model) {
            model.hasError = true;
            model.errorMessage = "Some validation error!"
          }

          $scope.model = model = {
            myField: 'my field value',
            hasError: false,
            errorMessage: '',
            changed: false
          };

          $scope.change = function() {
            model.hasError = false; // soon as the model changes unset the error.
          };

          $scope.doSomething = simulateError;
        }
      ]);
  </script>
  <!-- 
        snippet adapted from SO question
        NOTES: 
        - using ng-change to listen to input field changes
        - ng-trim="false" to listen to whitespace e.g spacebar
        - hide error when user uses text input field
    -->

  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-submit="doSomething(model)">
    <label for="my-field-id">Fill in:</label>
    <input type="text" id="my_field_id" ng-model="model.myField" ng-change="change()" ng-trim="false" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <div ng-show="model.hasError" ng-bind="model.errorMessage">
      Error from server goes here!
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/BNBgiT?p=preview